# Python Binomial Coefficient Confusion

Tags: python

Okay so we just got introduced to loops, and I've been scratching my head for days trying to figure it out. I'm trying to print pascal's triangle.
I found some code online that is simple and something that I can really understand!

```html
rows = int(input("Enter the number of rows : "))
for i in range(0, rows):
    coff = 1
    for j in range(1, rows-i):
        print("  ", end="")
    
    for k in range(0, i+1):
        print("  ", coff, end="")
        coff = int(coff * (i - k) / (k + 1))
    print()
```

However, how did they get this formula? `coff = int(coff * (i - k) / (k + 1))`,
I've been searching online on how they derived that, but I still can't find any answers.
I understand how the loop works but I'm scratching my head as to how they got the formula to get the terms. Help is appreciated!

Comment: They are [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). It is a nontrivial fact that they are exactly the numbers in Pascal's triangle. Proving that this is so is a typical example of proof by induction used in discrete math courses. In any event, why not write your own answer that you do understand, rather than searching online for solutions to your homework? A much better learning experience when you figure things out on your own.

Comment: Hi yes! I know that they are binomial coefficients but I was just unsure how he got that formula as the formula usually factorials: (n!/ k!(n-k)! This code is really the closest thing to what I know so far just the use of loops and arithmetic operations. I just found it baffling that the code outputs the exact binomial coefficient, while I still haven't found anything online that explains it.

Comment: Also, I've also tried using nested loops to get the factorial of each component of the formula (n!/k!(n-k)!), so I get n!, k! and (n-k)! and just combine them all together using variables. But my code isn't working the way it should and I get confused with the values of the indexes because I try to output it into a triangle.

Comment: I just really need to understand how the equation was derived

Comment: Using falling factorials you can write `n choose k` as a product of `k` factors in the numerator and `k` in the denominator. When you pass from `n choose k`  to `n choose (k+1)` you need 1 additional factor in the numerator and 1 in the denominator. These factors form the numerator and denominator of the factor you are multiplying by. But -- why do this for Pascal's triangle? If you want the whole triangle, just add pairs of consecutive numbers in one row together to get the next.

Answer (score 0):

For each position in Pascal's Triangle, the value is `i Choose k`, where `i` is the row (starting with 0 on the first row) and `k` is the position in the row (also starting with 0). `i` and `k` here (almost) matches with the variables in your code.

Now, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients) sports this identity:

[image]

The trick for transforming this into your code, is that `coff = int(coff * (i - k) / (k + 1))` runs after `coff` is printed, so we need to add 1 to `k`.
If you want the code closer to the formula, you could do the following:

```py
coff = 1
for k in range(1, i+2):
    print("  ", coff, end="")
    coff = int(coff * (i + 1 - k) / k)
```